# Setting up coordinates for NYC

Tags: coordinates, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, epsg

I have a project which involve me to map some random objects in NYC(Astoria Park, etc).
Now I'm using openalayer3 and osm to display a map, but I having a hard time understanding how to calculate coordinates for NYC.
I have made a map, but it is focused on city of London:

```
var city = ol.proj.transform([-0.12755, 51.507222], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

Coordinates for Astoria Park(40.780229N, 73.920935W), but obviously this are not the coordinates that I'm locking for, I have read about `ol.proj.transform`, but I can't understand how to calculate this.

Can someone explain me how can I overcome this and learn something, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers uses coordinates in the form of longitude, latitude. `40.780229,-73.920935` are the correct coordinates for Astoria Park, New York, however in latitude, longitude. Try `var city = ol.proj.transform([-73.920935, 40.780229], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');` instead.

Comment: Yes I have figured out last night, thank you for response.